# Blocking Queue Learning / Repeated Value Issue

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, blockingqueue

I am running into some issues when creating a Producer/Consumer threaded process.

So I used this test code to create a Producer and Consumer which correctly put() and take().

Consumer Code

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable {
    protected BlockingQueue queue = null;

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }
    public void run() {
        while (true)
        {
            try {
                String line = queue.take().toString();
                if(line.equals("EOF"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Capitolism is dead");
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("Consumed : " + line);
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Consumer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Producer Code

```
public class Producer implements Runnable 
{
    private BlockingQueue bq = null;
    public Producer(BlockingQueue queue) {
        this.setBlockingQueue(queue);
    }
    public void run() {
        int value = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println(bq.remainingCapacity());
            try {
                bq.put(value);
                System.out.println("Produced : " + value);
                value = value + 1;

                if(value > 10)
                {
                    bq.put("EOF");
                    System.out.println("ChildLabor is Abolished");
                    break;
                }
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public void setBlockingQueue(BlockingQueue bq) {
        this.bq = bq;
    }
}
```

Main program

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException 
    {
        java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue bq = new ArrayBlockingQueue(3);

        Producer producer = new Producer(bq);
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(bq);

        Thread ConsumerT = new Thread(consumer);
        Thread ProducerT = new Thread(producer);

        ProducerT.start();
        ConsumerT.start();

        ProducerT.join();
        ConsumerT.join();

        System.out.println("FINISHED");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

The Issue I am running into is when I try to go to the next level.

I expand on this code to have Producer read through a list of files storing all lines of each file into an ArrayList<>. This arraylist is then stored in the queue and the goal being a queue of ArrayList<> for Consumer to then read through and parse.

Producer at this point is working properly, It correctly reads through a list (holding till the queue has an open slot ect) and all peak() and take() work correctly.

The issue is then seemingly on the consumer side, I call take() but returns the first put() object over and over and over.

Example output would be

```
Produced File 201
Size : 1
Produced File 202
Size : 2
Produced File 203
Size : 3
Consumed File 203
Size : 2
Consumed File 203
Size : 1
Consumed File 203
Size : 0
```

I am not concerned with Consumed being called 3 times in a row, more concerned with how File 201 is being consumed over and over. Take() is properly reading off the first object, but doesn't seem to be removing it.

I tried variations of remove() peak() to see what was under the head however, none of this seemed to work.

To make it more confusing this process works perfectly when there is no delay, When put() is called and take() is called immediately after the file handling and head is working properly.

Looks like this

```
Produced File 201
Size : 1
Consumed File 201
Size : 0
```

The other Outcome I get when trying to solve this issue is

```
Produced File 201
Size : 1
Produced File 202
Size : 2
Produced File 203
Size : 3
Consumed File 203
Size : 2
Consumed File 203
Size : 1
```

Any help here or clarifications are appreciated.

*EDIT*
On my last run I added to the consumer 2 take() calls both of which returned the same value with size queue size decreasing.

It is also important to note that the take() will always return the last put(), So produced file 201, 202, 203 consumed 203 203, produced 204, 205 consumed 205, 205

Comment: How does the Consumer determine the file, based on the ArrayList it gets from the queue?